# Создание сферы в Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Как смоделировать сферу в Python с указанными пользователем центром и радиусом?

Сейчас есть что-то вроде этого:

```
import matplotlib as mtl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 5 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 5 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 5 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Первым делом гуглите "формула сферы", дальше, думаю, всё просто.

Comment: а что вас не устраивает в приведенном вами решении?

Comment: Это не мой код и совершенно не понимаю как из этого построить сферу с указанными пользователем центром и радиусом, туда еще необходимо вставить линию

Comment: Если вы совершенно не понимаете, то чего вы ждете от нас? чтобы мы написали код за вас? да еще и линию потом туда вставили?

Comment: Пытаюсь научиться это делать, понятно, что нужно отложить от заданного центра множество точек с длиною равной радиусу, но как это написать я действительно не знаю, потому и пришел сюда с этим вопросом. Если есть возможность расписать на каком-нибудь примере методологию процесса был бы очень признателен

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения радиуса изменяйте число перед `np.outer()`, а для изменения центра добавьте нужные координаты центра после `np.outer()`.

```py
x = 1 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) + 1
y = 1 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v)) + 1
z = 1 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) + 2
```

Таким образом у вас получится сфера с радиусом 1, и центром с координатами x = 1 , y = 1, z = 2.